# Invoke function on navigate to previous or next month of a kendoDatePicker

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, datepicker

I want to disable the weekends from being selected from a kendo date picker. Since I am using an old version of kendoUI (~2014), I cannot use the `disableDates` option (it is not supported).

Hence, I am disabling the weekends programmatically via a function which I named `disableWeekends()`, which is invoked as part of the `open` event. All good, until the user navigates to the previous or the next month - which renders the navigated month with the weekends enabled again.

Any suggestions on how I can call my `disableWeekends()` function everytime the user navigates to other months?

What I have tried so far:

1. **Using `navigate` event on date picker** -  It doesn't work, `navigate` seems to be not supported.
2. **Add `click` event on the target navigation elements** - The `click` event just doesn't get invoked: e.g. 

   `$('#some-static-ancestor').on('click', '.k-nav-next', function() {
       disableWeekends();
   });`

Note that using `mouseover` instead of `click` works, but doesn't solve the issue.

Anymore ideas/suggestions on how I can solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to eventually support disabling weekends on a KendoUI date picker with a sort of KendoUI date picker extension JS that I created for `kendo.all-2014.1.528.min.js`.

For my question on how to invoke the `disableWeekends()` function every time the user navigates to other months, I accomplished it by simply programmatically changing the `onclick` attribute value of the link element to to call the target function.

e.g.

`$(this).attr('onclick', 'disableWeekends()');`

where the `$(this)` element is the `.k-link` element.